GraphQL does not refresh after first attempt
Below is my LWC which is added as a quick action on Opportunity & fetches current Opportunity Contact Roles data and display it in the table. Here I have an option where I can edit Contact roles or even add new Contact Roles.
When I edit existing roles then refresh works fine but when I add new Contact roles, I see the new record in related List on Opportunity but when I click the same component then the newly created record is not visible. When I close and open the component again, it shows newly created records. It seems that graph ql wire does not refresh immediately.
Can someone please help me what changes I need to do in my lwc so that refresh works fine in all scenarios?
HTML:
<template>
    <lightning-quick-action-panel class="panel-color" header={label.Roles}>
        <lightning-card title={label.Roles} icon-name="standard:opportunity_contact_role">
            <div class="slds-m-around_medium container cmp-height">
                <template if:true={changeData}>
                    <c-l-w-c-lookup-custom-datatable
                        class="slds-max-medium-table_stacked"
                        onvaluechange={handleValueChange}
                        onlookupchanged={handleLookupChange}
                        oncellchange={handleCellChange}
                        onrowselection={handleRowSelection}
                        key-field="Id"
                        data={changeData}
                        columns={columns}
                        onedit={handleEdit}
                        draft-values={draftValues}
                        onsave={handleSave}
                        max-row-selection="1"
                        suppress-bottom-bar=true
                        selected-rows={preSelectedRows}>
                    </c-l-w-c-lookup-custom-datatable>
                </template>
            </div>
            <div slot="footer" class="footer-fixed">
                <lightning-button variant="neutral" label={label.AddRow} onclick={handleAddRow}></lightning-button> 
                &nbsp;<lightning-button variant="neutral" label={label.Cancel} onclick={closeAction}></lightning-button> 
                &nbsp;<lightning-button variant="brand" label={label.SaveAndClose} onclick={handleSave}></lightning-button> 
            </div>
        </lightning-card>
    </lightning-quick-action-panel>
</template>

JS:
import {
    LightningElement,
    track,
    api,
    wire
} from 'lwc';
import {
    refreshApex
} from '@salesforce/apex';
import fetchRelatedListRecords from '@salesforce/apex/ContactRolesController.fetchRelatedListRecords';
import {
    gql,
    graphql,
    refreshGraphQL
} from 'lightning/uiGraphQLApi';
import upsertRoles from '@salesforce/apex/ContactRolesController.upsertContactRoles';
import CONTACT_ROLE_OBJECT from '@salesforce/schema/OpportunityContactRole';
import ROLE_FIELD from '@salesforce/schema/OpportunityContactRole.Role';
import EditContactRole from '@salesforce/label/c.Edit_Contact_Roles';
import AddRow from '@salesforce/label/c.add';
import ToastErrorTitle from '@salesforce/label/c.error-occur';
import ToastSuccessTitle from '@salesforce/label/c.success-msg';
import Cancel from '@salesforce/label/c.Cancel';
import SaveAndClose from '@salesforce/label/c.save';

import {
    NavigationMixin
} from 'lightning/navigation';
import {
    CloseActionScreenEvent
} from 'lightning/actions';
import {
    getObjectInfo,
    getPicklistValues
} from 'lightning/uiObjectInfoApi';
import {
    masterRecordTypeId
} from './utils.js';
import {
    showToast
} from 'c/toastMessageUtil'; //Display Toast Message from generic component
const columns = [{
        label: 'Name',
        fieldName: 'Name',
        title: 'Name',
        type: 'lookup',
        editable: false,
        typeAttributes: {
            placeholder: 'Choose Contact',
            object: 'OpportunityContactRole',
            fieldName: 'ContactId',
            label: 'Contact',
            value: {
                fieldName: 'ContactId'
            },
            context: {
                fieldName: 'Id'
            },
            variant: 'label-hidden',
            name: 'Contact',
            fields: ['Contact.Name'],
            target: '_self'
        }
    },
    {
        label: 'Role',
        fieldName: 'Role',
        type: 'picklist',
        editable: false,
        typeAttributes: {
            placeholder: 'Choose Role',
            options: {
                fieldName: 'pickListOptions'
            },
            value: {
                fieldName: 'Role'
            }, 
            context: {
                fieldName: 'Id'
            }, 
            label: 'Role',
            variant: 'label-hidden',
            name: 'Role'
        }
    }
]

export default class EditContactRoles extends NavigationMixin(LightningElement) {
    timeoutId;
    @api recordId; //Fetch Opportunity Id and based on this, OpportunityContactRole info fetches

    @api mode;
    recordTypeIdRole = '';
    keyIndex = 0;
    contacts;
    selectedContacts;
    primaryContactRoleToBeInserted;
    otherContactRolesToBeInserted;
    preSelectedRows = ["NA"];
    error;
    columns = columns;
    datas = [];
    @track dataPickist = [];
    draftValues = [];
    lastSavedData = [];
    @track pickListOptions;
    @track contactDataList;
    //used to obtain the picklist as private children of datatable
    privateChildren = {};
    callWire = false;
    userPermissionsArray = [];
    label = {
        EditContactRole,
        ToastErrorTitle,
        ToastSuccessTitle,
        SaveAndClose,
        Cancel,
        AddRow
    };
    @track wiredActivity = [];
    showSpinner=false;
    spinnerVariant='brand';
    spinnerMessage='Loading..';
    _timeout;
    graphqlData;
    url;
    opportunityURL;
    @wire(getObjectInfo, {
        objectApiName: CONTACT_ROLE_OBJECT
    })
    objectInfo;

    //fetch picklist options
    @wire(getPicklistValues, {
        recordTypeId: masterRecordTypeId,
        fieldApiName: ROLE_FIELD
    })
    wirePickList({
        error,
        data
    }) {
        if (data) {
            this.pickListOptions = data.values;
            this.callWire = true;
        } else if (error) {
            console.log(error);
        }
    }
    constructor() {
        super();
    }

    handleAddRow() {
        let copyData = this.datas;
        copyData.push({
            Id: this.keyIndex,
            OpportunityId: this.recordId,
            ContactId: null,
            IsPrimary: false,
            Role: null,
            Name: null,
            conLink: null,
            pickListOptions: this.pickListOptions,
            roleClass: 'slds-cell-edit',
            contactNameClass: 'slds-cell-edit'
        });
        this.keyIndex = this.keyIndex + 1;
        this.datas = [...copyData];
        //refreshApex(this.datas);
    }


    closeAction() {
        this.dispatchEvent(new CloseActionScreenEvent());
    }



    updateDataValues(updateItem) {
        let copyData = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.datas));

        copyData.forEach(item => {
            if (item.Id === updateItem.Id) {
                for (let field in updateItem) {
                    item[field] = updateItem[field];
                }
            }
        });

        //write changes back to original data
        this.datas = [...copyData];
    }

    updateDraftValues(updateItem) {
        let draftValueChanged = false;
        let copyDraftValues = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.draftValues));
        //store changed value to do operations
        //on save. This will enable inline editing &
        //show standard cancel & save button
        copyDraftValues.forEach(item => {
            if (item.Id === updateItem.Id) {
                for (let field in updateItem) {
                    item[field] = updateItem[field];
                }
                draftValueChanged = true;
            }
        });

        if (draftValueChanged) {
            this.draftValues = [...copyDraftValues];
        } else {
            this.draftValues = [...copyDraftValues, updateItem];
        }
    }

    //handler to handle cell changes & update values in draft values
    handleCellChange(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        this.updateDraftValues(event.detail.draftValues[0]);
    }



    handleRowSelection(event) {
        var selectedRecords = this.template.querySelector("c-l-w-c-lookup-custom-datatable").getSelectedRows();
        event.stopPropagation();
        let updatedItem;
        if (selectedRecords[0] && selectedRecords[0].Id) {
            updatedItem = {
                Id: selectedRecords[0].Id,
                IsPrimary: true
            };
            this.updateDraftValues(updatedItem);
            this.updateDataValues(updatedItem);
        }
    }

    handleValueChange(event) {
        event.stopPropagation();
        let dataRecieved = event.detail.data;
        let updatedItem;
        if (dataRecieved.label == 'Role') {
            updatedItem = {
                Id: dataRecieved.context,
                Role: dataRecieved.value
            };
            this.setClasses(dataRecieved.context, 'roleClass', 'slds-cell-edit slds-is-edited');
        } else if (dataRecieved.label == 'Contact') {
            updatedItem = {
                Id: dataRecieved.context,
                ContactId: dataRecieved.value
            };
            this.setClasses(dataRecieved.context, 'contactNameClass', 'slds-cell-edit slds-is-edited');
        } else {
            this.setClasses(dataRecieved.context, '', '');
        }
        this.updateDraftValues(updatedItem);
        this.updateDataValues(updatedItem);
    }

    handleEdit(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        let dataRecieved = event.detail.data;
        if (dataRecieved.label === 'Role' || dataRecieved.label === 'Contact') {
            this.setClasses(dataRecieved.context, 'roleClass', 'slds-cell-edit');
        } else {
            this.setClasses(dataRecieved.context, '', '');
        }
    }


    setClasses(id, fieldName, fieldValue) {
        this.datas = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.datas));
        this.datas.forEach((detail) => {
            if (detail.Id === id) {
                detail[fieldName] = fieldValue;
            }
        });
    }

    handleSave(event) {
        console.log('Calling handlesave..');
        event.preventDefault();
        this.showSpinners();
        this.showTable = false;
        const updatedFields = this.draftValues;
        const oppId = this.recordId;
        let copyData = this.datas;
        this.datas = [...copyData];
        // Call upsertRoles and refreshApex with Promise chaining
        upsertRoles({
                rolesforUpdate: updatedFields,
                oppId: oppId
            })
            .then(() => {
                this.dispatchEvent(
                    showToast('success', 'dismissable', '', this.label.ToastSuccessTitle)
                );
                this.hideSpinner();
                //Once Update Navigate to Parent Record detail page.
                window.clearTimeout(this._timeout);
                this._timeout = setTimeout(() => {
                    this.navigateToRecord();
                }, 2000);
               
            }).catch((error) => {
                this.dispatchEvent(
                    showToast('error', 'dismissable', '', this.label.ToastErrorTitle)
                );
                console.log('error:', error);
                this.hideSpinner();
            })

            
    }
    handleCancel(event) {
        //remove draftValues & revert data changes
        this.datas = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.lastSavedData));
        this.draftValues = [];
    }

    navigateToRecord() {
      this.opportunityURL=  this[NavigationMixin.Navigate]({
            type: 'standard__recordPage',
            attributes: {
                recordId: this.recordId,
                actionName: 'view'
            }
        });
        this[ NavigationMixin.GenerateUrl ]( this.opportunityURL )
        .then( url => this.url = url );
    }
    //Graph  QL to fetch data
    @wire(graphql, {
        query: "$contactRoleQuery",
        variables: "$queryData",
    })
    graphqlQueryResult({
        data,
        errors
    }) {
        console.log('graphqlData.'+JSON.stringify(this.datas));
        if (data) {
            console.log('Wire called.');
            this.wiredActivity = [];
            this.wiredActivity = data.uiapi.query.OpportunityContactRole.edges.map(edge => edge.node);
            this.datas = [];
            if(this.wiredActivity!==undefined){
                this.wiredActivity.map((row) => {
                    if (row.IsPrimary) {
                        this.preSelectedRows = [];
                        this.preSelectedRows.push(row.Id);
                    }
                    this.datas.push( {
                        Id: row.Id,
                        OpportunityId: row.OpportunityId.value,
                        ContactId: row.ContactId.value,
                        IsPrimary: row.IsPrimary.value,
                        Role: row.Role.value,
                        Name: row.Contact.Name.value,
                        conLink: '/' + row.ContactId.value,
                        pickListOptions: this.pickListOptions,
                        roleClass: 'slds-cell-edit',
                        contactNameClass: 'slds-cell-edit'
                    });
                });
                this.graphqlData = this.datas;
            }
            
            this.error = undefined;
        } else if (errors) {
            console.log('Errors in Wire Graph QL..' + JSON.stringify(errors));
        }
    }
    get contactRoleQuery() {
        return gql `
      query contactRoleDetails($oppId: ID!) {
        uiapi {
          query {
            OpportunityContactRole(where: { 
            OpportunityId: { eq: $oppId },
            }) {
              edges {
                node {
                  Id
                  ContactId{value}
                  OpportunityId{value}
                  Role{value}
                  IsPrimary{value}
                  Contact{
                  Name{value}
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    `;
    }
    get queryData() {
        return {
            oppId: this.recordId
        };
    }
    // try to call refresh button on button click or after save button event but does not work.
  async refresh() {
    console.log('Calling refresh...');
    try{
         return refreshGraphQL(this.datas);
    }
    catch (err) {
        console.log('Error during refresh'+JSON.stringify(err));
    }
    
  }
    get isVisible() {
        return this.datas.length > 0 ? true : false;
    }
    showSpinners() {
        this.spinnerMessage = 'Saving..';
        this.spinnerVariant = 'brand';
        this.showSpinner = true;
    }
    hideSpinner() {
        window.clearTimeout(this._timeout);
        this._timeout = setTimeout(() => {
            this.showSpinner = false;
        }, 1200);
    }

    get changeData(){
        return this.datas.length>0?this.datas:undefined
    }
}

c-l-w-c-lookup-custom-datatable also calls child component which shows lookup & dropdown field. I did not add those code here it may not be needed but if needed, I will add the same.

Wires always use client-side caches, which is why refreshGraphQL exists specifically for graphql wires. Make sure you invoke it to clear the cache and have the results re-fetched whenever you expect the results can change. This article might help you - I haven't confirmed the quality of it.

@PhilW I already referred this article but in my case once I save the record I even tried to call refresh() method or even tried to call it on click on separate button but it does not call wire graphql explicitly. I am not sure if graphql have any limitations with LWC quick action?

Variables and functions that use @wire annotation are always using cache. Build-in wire adapters have scenarios when they refresh automatically, for example record changed in the context of current page will refresh @wire(getRecord) which has Id of this record
For GraphQL there is refreshGraphQL function that can be called in order to refresh result of @wire(graphql). From the code snippet you have provided I can see that there is method that uses this function. But it will not work as you expect, because refreshGraphQL requires wired result as input, but not data itself. In this case
Instead of
@wire(graphql, {
  query: "$contactRoleQuery",
  variables: "$queryData",
})
graphqlQueryResult({
  data,
  errors
}) {

  if (data) {
    this.datas = this.getRecordsFromGraphQl(data); // this function represents actions made to transform GraphQl data as in original code
  } else if (error) {
    this.error = error;
  }
  
}

async refresh() {
  try{
    return refreshGraphQL(this.datas);
  } catch (err) {
    console.log('Error during refresh'+JSON.stringify(err));
  }
}

Correct implementation of refreshGraphQL
graphqlWiredResult = null;

@wire(graphql, {
  query: "$contactRoleQuery",
  variables: "$queryData",
})
graphqlQueryResult(result) {
  this.graphqlWiredResult = result;
  const { data, error } = this.graphqlWiredResult;

  if (data) {
    this.datas = this.getRecordsFromGraphQl(data); // this function represents actions made to transform GraphQl data as in original code
  } else if (error) {
    this.error = error;
  }
  
}

async refresh() {
  try{
    return refreshGraphQL(this.graphqlWiredResult);
  } catch (err) {
    console.log('Error during refresh'+JSON.stringify(err));
  }
}

From: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/platform/lwc/guide/reference-refreshgraphql.html#syntax

Hi @Paul, Could you please elaborate what this.getRecordsFromGraphQl(data) method is? What it represents? I dont have any such methods in my code.

Hi @SFDCDJ. It is just a placeholder which is not important for the explanation. It represents all logic that you have inside your if(data) {} block.

I did try this approach earlier but I missed this steps to put this variables to proper positions.
this.graphqlWiredResult = result;
const { data, error } = this.graphqlWiredResult;
It works now. Thank you so much for your help!
